# Usage Twitter Stream api for search

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i`m trying use Twitter Stream Api for searching some hashtags in Google Spreadsheet. Twitter search api useless cause i wanna trak retweet count too. My function sample here. Can anybody explain me what i must do for working well..

```
function miniSearch(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sumSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Readme/Settings");
  // Authorize to Twitter
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("twitter");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
  // "twitter" value must match the argument to "addOAuthService" above.
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    "oAuthServiceName" : "twitter",
    "oAuthUseToken" : "always"
  };

  var url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track="+"twitterapi";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var tweets = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  sumSheet.getRange('B8').setValue(tweets[0]["text"]);



}
```

this function return error code 504;

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google Apps Script can keep a persistent HTTP connection open which is resulting in the 504 (See [Twitter Streaming APIs Doc](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis))

[I've a basic retweet counter in [this Google Spreadsheet Template (TAGS v4.0)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqGkLMU9sHmLdHg1RnVkVnNLX3p0YlJYXzExdEVqWGc#gid=117). The filterUnique formula uses this code (the pseudocode is strip out any links from tweet text then extract 1st 90% of text (to take account of any old style RT+ annotation), then if not in unique array add or add 1 to existing value):

```
function filterUnique(tweets){
  var output = [];
  var temp = {};
  for (i in tweets){
    if (i>0){
      var tmp = tweets[i][0];
      var urlPattern = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
      tmp = tmp.replace(urlPattern,"")
      tmp = tmp.substring(0,parseInt(tmp.length*0.9));
      if (temp[tmp] == undefined){
        temp[tmp] = [tweets[i][0],0];
      }
      temp[tmp] = [tweets[i][0],temp[tmp][1]+1]; 
    }
  }
  for (i in temp){
    output.push([temp[i][0],temp[i][1]]);
  }
  output.sort(function(a,b) {
    return  b[1]-a[1];
  });
  return output.slice(0, 12);
}
```

]

Comment: i think it will not work for me, cause i must search some hashtags and then in founded tweets i must track how many times retweeted every tweet.. and it is a lot of connect and throw over limit of API

Comment: What you are trying to do may be beyond mere mortals with regular api access. You might want to start looking at 3rd party services like datasift.com which have pay as you go access to twitter data

Comment: i think it not that professional task. the only problem is i can`t connect to stream api for any type of action..